# Difference between intercepts from `lm` (AR(1)) and `arima` functions

Tags: r, lm

I have obtained different values of intercept from autoregressive AR(1) model calculated with `lm` and  `arima`, but coefficients before lagged variable are almost exactly the same, intercept for `arima` is `0.1153` and `0.03014` for `lm` why does this difference occurs ?

```
> set.seed(123)
> ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 1000, list(ar = 0.8, sd = 1)) #simulated dataset
> arima(ar1, order=c(1,0,0)) #AR(1) model

Call:
arima(x = ar1, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.7772     0.1153
s.e.  0.0200     0.1418

sigma^2 estimated as 1.006:  log likelihood = -1422.16,  aic = 2850.33
> summary(lm(ar1[-1]~ar1[-1000]))

Call:
lm(formula = ar1[-1] ~ ar1[-1000])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8835 -0.6563 -0.0029  0.6587  3.1793 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.03014    0.03181   0.947    0.344    
ar1[-1000]   0.77612    0.02000  38.802   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.003 on 997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6016,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6012 
F-statistic:  1506 on 1 and 997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 3):

Stationary time series estimation first starts by centering. So the intercept estimation in `arima` is just `mean(ar1)`.

Turning to `lm`. Did you not see that the intercept is not statistically different from 0, as `ar1[-1]` and `ar1[-1000]` have the same mean? That's what stationarity implies.

In summary, `arima` here is doing real estimation for `ar1`, while `lm` is only estimating its auto-correlation. You are doing different things!

---

If this is still not that clear for you, let's just focus on the `lm` usage in general.

```
# true model: y = 0.7 x + 0.5
x <- runif(1000)
y <- 0.5 + 0.7 * x + rnorm(1000, 0, 0.05)

# a proper estimation
lm(y ~ x)

# now center x and y so they have the same mean: 0
# this only estimates slope
x1 <- x - mean(x)
y1 <- y - mean(y)
lm(y1 ~ x1)
```